# How to set up timezones in a GKE Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, timezone, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed docker Linux to gcloud gke pod.

I added the code bellow, trying to set up the time zone in the dockerfile. This code is running correctly in a local docker. But it does not work in gcloud gke pod.  The timezones are in local PST, timezones in GKE Pod are still in UTC. Please help!

```
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this is working on your local environment. Looks like you are missing (Ubuntu, Debian):

```
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

So in summary something like this:

```
echo America/Los_Angeles >/etc/timezone && \
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime && \
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

This [blog](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2015/10/31/time-in-docker-containers/) has a very good explanation, including how to do it [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/).