# How to set TimeZone in Kubernate pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

If I configured Kubermate in local machine then kubernate pod showing time UTC time.
If I configure Kubermate in AWS machine then kubernate pod showing some different time.
So how can i configure time in Kubernate pods on our requirement time zone. I need configure it because i am facing problem on checking log file.

Comment: Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089265/kubernetes-timezone-in-pod-with-command-and-argument

Comment: I changed this then also my logger of Pod having UTC time.

Comment: Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331463/how-to-set-up-timezones-in-a-gke-pod/53332870#53332870) which offers the other approach how to synchronize time between k8s Pods.